# mega-dropdown menu как изменить скорость открытия?

Tags: bootstrap, menu

Очень быстро выпадает, как замедлить скорость

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav_1">
                    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown active">
                        <a href="https://xn----ftbbenqb7b.xn--p1ai/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/icons/bithim.png" width="23"> Бытовая химия<span class="caret"></span></a>              
                        <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu w3ls_vegetables_menu">
                            <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
                                <ul>    
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/antistatiki-kondicionery/">Антистатики, кондиционеры</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/dispensery-dlya-osvezhiteley-vozduha/">Диспенсеры для освежителей воздуха</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/dispensery-dlya-pennogo-i-zhidkogo-myla/">Диспенсеры для пенного и жидкого мыла</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/zhiroudaliteli-i-sredstva-dlya-kuhni/">Жироудалители и средства для кухни</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/kosmeticheskie-tovary/">Косметические товары</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/mylo-zhidkoe/">Мыло жидкое</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/mylo-kuskovoe/">Мыло кусковое</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/osvezhiteli-vozduha-aerozol-nye/">Освежители воздуха аэрозольные</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/osvezhiteli-dlya-unitazov-i-pisuarov/">Освежители для унитазов и писуаров</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/osvezhiteli-mikrosprei/">Освежители микроспреи</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/otbelivateli-pyatnovyvoditeli-krahmaly/">Отбеливатели, пятновыводители</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/poliroli-sredstva-dlya-mebeli-i-orgtehniki/">Полироли, средства для мебели и оргтехники</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/poroshki-stiral-nye/">Порошки стиральные</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/professional-naya-himiya-shz/">Профессиональная химия СХЗ</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-dezinfekcii-i-universal-nye-chistyaschie/">Средства для дезинфекции и универсальные чистящие</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-polov-i-napol-nyh-pokrytiy/">Средства для полов и напольных покрытий</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-posudomoechnyh-mashin-i-parokonvektomatov/">Средства для посудомоечных машин и пароконвектоматов</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-santehniki/">Средства для сантехники</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-stekol-i-zerkal/">Средства для стекол и зеркал</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-dlya-udaleniya-nakipi/">Средства для удаления накипи</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-moyuschie-dlya-posudy/">Средства моющие для посуды</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/bytovaya-i-professional-naya-himiya/sredstva-ot-nasekomyh/">Средства от насекомых</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                  
                        </div>              
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown active">
                        <a href="https://xn----ftbbenqb7b.xn--p1ai/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri()); ?>/icons/clean.png" width="23"> Материалы для уборки<span class="caret"></span></a>               
                        <div class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu w3ls_vegetables_menu">
                            <div class="w3ls_vegetables">
                                <ul>    
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/vantuzy-ershi/">Вантузы, ерши</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/vedra-telezhki-uborochnye-veniki-metly/">Ведра, тележки уборочные, веники</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/gubki-mochalki/">Губки, мочалки</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/konteynery-baki-urny-korziny-dlya-musora/">Контейнеры, баки, урны, корзины для мусора</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/meshki-musornye-30-60-120-180-240/">Мешки мусорные,30, 60, 120, 180, 240</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/nasadki-derzhateli-i-rukoyatki-dlya-shvabr/">Насадки,держатели и рукоятки для швабр</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/salfetki-universal-nye/">Салфетки универсальные</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/sgony-skrebki-sovki-schetki/">Сгоны, скребки, совки, щетки</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/tkan-vafel-naya/">Ткань вафельная</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://лидер-гк.рф/catalog/inventar-i-materialy-dlya-uborki/tryapki-dlya-polov/">Тряпки для пола</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>                  
                        </div>              
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается через Jquery

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(!0, !0).slideDown("slow"), $(this).toggleClass("open")
    }, function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu", this).stop(!0, !0).slideUp("slow"), $(this).toggleClass("open")
    })
});

Где значения slideDown("slow")  либо slow 600мс или fast 200мс